# Javascript: Searching within Header

Tags: javascript, header, innerhtml

document.body.innerHTML works to search within the body.

Is there a similar function for searching within the "Head" section?

I've been searching for a while, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0];
```

Comment: thanks, i have noticed some problems with that when trying to pull data from <meta> tags in the header using this, but it is probably the right way.

Comment: @user1124535 what problem are you experiencing with this method? this is correct and will work, as long as you *execute it at the appropriate time* ...

Comment: got it. that's why. i was trying to do reg expressions on the header.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` is how you would select the head element.

Answer (score 0):

the following will do what you need:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are aiming for but using getElementsByTagName
should to the trick.

For Example

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the `head` element like so...

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

The `||` just allows you to use the (probably) faster built in property that is available in most browsers.